# Can I set a standart to FullSimplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm working with a multiple solution equation, where must roots differ by minus signs.
The Mathematica output (after FullSimplify) is of the type:
 $\frac{a-b}{-1+X^2}$

Is there a way to force every denominator to be $1-X^2$ instead?

Comment: Does `(-Numerator[expr])/(-Denominator[expr])` work for you?

Comment: Display what J.M. recommended with `TraditionalForm`, i.e., `(expr2 = (-Numerator[expr])/(-Denominator[expr])) // TraditionalForm`

Comment: It prints the same thing :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, this is one of difficult tasks in Mma. It is because it has an internal way of ordering. The only way to reverse it is to use such functions as Hold or HoldForm. Aftre that, however, you will be unable to operate your expression further. If this is OK with you, you may use the function

```
factorMinus[expr_, fun_: Identity] := (-1)*
  HoldForm[Evaluate[fun[(-1)*expr]]]
```

Here expr is the expression, where you want to change the sign, fun is an optional function that you apply to `-expr` if necessary.

Example 1: In this case we straightforwardly change the sign of an expression

```
factorMinus[-1 + x^2]
```

[image]

Example 2: Here we need not to change the sign of the whole expression, but of one of its subexpressiopns. In such a case, one has to map the function factorMinus onto this subexpression:

```
expr = (a - b)/(-1 + x^2);

MapAt[factorMinus, expr, {2, 1}]
```

[image]

If you need to further operate with such expressions you have to apply `ReleaseHold` to them. Be careful, sometimes it is enough to apply it straightforwardly:

```
expr//ReleaseHold
```

but in some cases, it does not work and you should map it onto all levels of the expression like this:

```
Map[ReleaseHold, expr, Infinity]
```

Have fun!